# Selecting a Word Interop Header Range causes Word to switch to Draft View

Tags: c#, view, range, office-interop

When selecting a Header Range using `.Select()`, Microsoft Word automatically switches to Draft View from my current view type (Print layout). How do I stop Word from switching to Draft View?

The following code example demonstrates what I'm doing:

```
 // this.Document is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
 Section section = this.Document.Sections.First;
 foreach (HeaderFooter header in section.Headers)
 {
   if (header.Exists) 
   {
     header.Range.Select(); // When I call this, Word switches to Draft View.
     break;
   }
 }
```

**Edit (3):**

Apparently saving the View Type and resetting it does work. However, this causes a annoying flickering when Word switches to Draft View and then back to Print Layout. Additionally, when I double click in the main document space to get out of the header section, Word switches back to Draft View.

```
 WdViewType viewType = this.Document.ActiveWindow.View.Type;
 range.Select();
 this.Document.ActiveWindow.View.Type = viewType;
```

Comment: Found a scenario where an exception is thrown - see my answer for a fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `View.SeekView` property must be set for all view types excluding wdNormalView (Draft View) before the range is selected.

```
var window = this.Document.ActiveWindow;
// wdNormalView == Draft View, where SeekView can't be used and isn't needed.
if (window.View.Type != WdViewType.wdNormalView)
{
  // -1 Not Header/Footer, 0 Even page header, 1 Odd page header, 4 First page header
  // 2 Even page footer, 3 Odd page footer, 5 First page footer
  int rangeType = range.Information[WdInformation.wdHeaderFooterType];
  if (rangeType == 0 || rangeType == 1 || rangeType == 4)
    window.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
  if (rangeType == 2 || rangeType == 3 || rangeType == 5)
    window.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter;
}
header.Range.Select();
```

Comment: Found a scenario where an exception is thrown - see my answer for a fix

Answer (score 1):

7 years later, but in using Joe W's answer in my `Word VSTO Addin`, I ran into an issue and decided to post the fix here:

Before `View.SeekView` is set to `WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader` or `WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter`, check to see if `View.SeekView` is already set to a header or footer value. If it is, an exception is thrown because the current `View.SeekView` can't be changed to `wdSeekCurrentPageHeader` if `View.SeekView` is already set to a header value and the current `View.SeekView` can't be changed to `wdSeekCurrentPageFooter` if `View.SeekView` is already set to a footer value. This could be the case if the user is editing a header or footer when the code is executed to adjust the view setting (e.g., in a Word VSTO Addin).

This code works. It includes code to save the `View.SeekView` setting as it exists before calling `SetView` and reset it after the call to `SetView`. This takes into account the scenario where the user is editing a header or footer when `SetView` is called as might be the case in a `Word VSTO Addin`.

```
// ... some Word VSTO Addin code that calls SetView 

Word.WdSeekView enumSavedSeekView = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView;

bool viewResetNeeded = SetView(workingStoryRange);

if (viewResetNeeded)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = enumSavedSeekView;
}

// ... end of some Word VSTO Addin code that calls SetView 

private bool SetView(Word.Range range)
{
    bool viewResetNeeded = false;

    // wdNormalView == Draft View, where SeekView can't be used and isn't needed.
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type != Word.WdViewType.wdNormalView)
    {
        // -1 Not Header/Footer, 0 Even page header, 1 Odd page header, 4 First page header
        // 2 Even page footer, 3 Odd page footer, 5 First page footer

        switch (range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdHeaderFooterType])
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 4:

                if ((Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView != Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekEvenPagesHeader) && (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView != Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekFirstPageHeader) && (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView != Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekPrimaryHeader))
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
                    viewResetNeeded = true;
                }

                break;

            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 5:

                if ((Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView != Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekEvenPagesFooter) && (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView != Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekFirstPageFooter) && (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView != Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekPrimaryFooter))
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter;
                    viewResetNeeded = true;
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return viewResetNeeded;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize the Words collection in the range object to select the header

```
 Section section = this.Document.Sections.First;
 foreach (HeaderFooter header in section.Headers)
 {
   if (header.Exists) 
   {
     header.Range.Words.First.Select()
     break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not having any trouble selecting the header... that's what `header.Range.Select();` is doing. I'm having trouble with Word switching to Draft View when I select the header.

Comment: @Joe W  I am aware hence why I supplied the code.  It selects the header and does not switch to Draft View.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, I tried your exact code and it does not work. It still switches to Draft View, but now it just selects the first word in the Header instead of the entire Range.